# Macros formatting worksheet as xlsm instead of pdf

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro that once a button is clicked on a worksheet a new Outlook email is generated with the worksheet as an attachment.

When recording the macro and then looking at the format in the code it is saying pdf. When I trial the button the attachment is formatted as a xlsm.

```
Sub email()
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\ROANDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Purchase Order Turkey MASTER Version 2.pdf" _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show
End Sub
```

I'm completely new to VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice try.  :)   but...

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show
```

...is the VBA equivalent of clicking `File` → `Send` (or `Share` in some versions), which opens an e-mail message in Microsoft Outlook **with the current workbook attached.**

You have 2 lines of code there. The first line exports the Active Workbook to a PDF file located at `C:\Users\ROANDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Purchase Order Turkey MASTER Version 2.pdf`.

That is unrelated to the next line (a hint being a fact that the 2nd line doesn't mention a filename, variable, etc.).

I'm always been a fan of the beginner technique of recording a macro doing what you want VBA to do, and then adjust as required, but some things do get missed (or ignored) by the Macro Recorder, probably like in this case.

1st, can you please confirm that the PDF exists (at the path above) and has the correct data that you want to email?  Also which version of Excel are you using?  (next time add the tag for your version when posting your question, like [excel-2016](/questions/tagged/excel-2016) etc.)

After that's steps verified working, we can move on to emailing the PDF...